# The light on my power button remains on even after I shut down my laptop and cannot restart it

Tags: dual-boot, shutdown

I recently bought a new laptop - a Lenovo ThinkPad-e495. I have dual booted Ubuntu since then. Initially, I had Ubuntu 19.10 and had no problems. Then I upgraded to 20.04. Now I cant restart my laptop and even after I shut down my computer the light on the Power button and Esc button remains on.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 19.10 thinking it would solve the problem but it didn't solve itself.

I have Windows 10 on separate Partition and it shuts down perfectly fine and the lights get turned off. I only have this problem in Ubuntu.

Specs:

- RAM: 16 GB
- Processor: AMD® Ryzen 7 3700u with Radeon vega mobile gfx × 8
- Graphics: AMD® Raven
- GNOME: 3.34.1
- OS-type: 64 bit
- Disk: 512,1 GB

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: Just... it happens to me too.
Lenovo Ideapad L340 Ryzen 7
After sudo demicode -s bios-version i get this: ARCN32WW

Comment: @heynnema I got this: R11ET30W (1.10 )

Comment: @Lobon Please start a new question with your details.

Comment: @heynnema, please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246900/after-shutting-off-ubuntu-my-computer-doesnt-turn-off-completely-i-must-use-t
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lenovo Thinkpad E490

You have a very old BIOS, R11ET30W (1.10 ).

There's a newer BIOS available, R0YET43W (1.26), available for download [here](https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/downloads/ds506071) or [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-e590-type-20nb-20nc/downloads/ds506071).

**Note**: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RoshanDhakal Great news! Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem only I have an Asus. Will this solution work for me or do I need to download a totally different bios?