# F1 light stays on even after powering off dual boot Ubuntu machine

Tags: dual-boot, shutdown, lenovo, bios

Ubuntu 22.04 is set up in dual boot mode after legacy Windows partition was shrunk on a Lenovo X1 Carbon Thinkpad 4th generation.  After shutting down Ubuntu via the GUI or `sudo poweroff` in the terminal the machine turns off but the LED light on the <kbd>F1</kbd> key stays on.  When powering off from Windows, the same light turns off.

Additionally, I need to hard shut-off the light by holding down the power button before starting up the machine normally.

Do I need to update my [BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246275/the-light-on-my-power-button-remains-on-even-after-i-shut-down-my-laptop-and-can)? FWIW it is: N1FET74W (1.48 )

*Update*
If my sound is on, the <kbd>F1</kbd> light stays off (since it indicates speakers off) when my computer is shutdown.  However, because something is still consuming power, without hard shutting off down the machine, the battery gets drained.

**Update 2 2022-06-29**
A recent update to Ubuntu seems to have fixed this issue.  The light no longer stays on if I turn my machine off.  Thank you to whoever fixed this on the Ubuntu project!